# GTX 1060 (3GB) is getting hotter (and running worse) than GTX 1050?

Tags: gpu

I have the following system: FX 8350 GTX 1060 (3GB) 16 GB RAM Windows 7

My Girlfriend got this setup: FX 4300 GTX 1050 16 GB RAM Windows 7

We both play the same game (No Man's Sky) with the same settings (Low), same resolution (720p), we both play offline, have nothing running in the background (except the same antivirus system), both having the same gpu driver with the same settings in the Nvidia control panel etc. But the game runs way better on her system. The GTX 1050 from my GF is getting about 42 - 43°C and she mostly gets 60 FPS My GTX 1060 is getting about 57 - 60 °C and i get 40 - 60 FPS. We also both have that game running on a ssd.

I think that there is something wrong with my system, but i have no clue how to find out what is going wrong. Both of our graphics cards are about 1,5 years old. Based on our systems, the game should run better on my system, but it doesn't.

I'm not jealous, but i want to find out what's going wrong with my system.

Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: Is the PSU big enough for the 1060?

Comment: Do you have the same case?  Is it in the same slot?  What card is next to it?  All of these can influence temperature and performance

Answer (score 1):

The
[FX-8350](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-8350)
compared with the
[FX-4300](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-4300)
have two interesting differences:

| Specification | FX-4300 | FX-8350 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Default TDP / TDP | 95W | 125W |
| Max Temps | 70.5°C | 61°C |

We can see that the FX-8350 consumes more power but can only tolerate
lower temperatures. In addition, in your tests it's getting pretty close
to its maximal temperature, perhaps aided by the fact that it's using more power.

As modern CPUs and GPUs have safeguards that slow them down automatically when
the temperature is too high, this might be what is happening in your case.

I would also guess that your computer is not as well ventilated as the other
computer, perhaps because of a poorer internal setup, or perhaps because
of clogged airways. This might be the reason that it's heating up too much.

You should also check whether the game uses the CPU or the GPU to generate
the video, using the Task Manager's Performance tab. If it's not using the
GPU, some adjustment may be needed to stop it from using the CPU.